# Help finding this game

Tags: game-identification

[image]

I had this game long time ago but I forgot its name and all I have is this picture. Can anyone help me to find its name?

Comment: The kind of game is definitely a "spot the difference". There’s just... 1000s of them so I can’t answer what the exact game is.

Comment: I spot 10 differences - rot13(Xvq'f zhyyrg, obbxf ba furys, uvtuyvtug ba onyybba, cngpu ba ohpxrg, graavf onyy, oyhr erpgnatyr, naq erq obbx ba tebhaq, gncr ba yrsg sbertebhaq obk, yrsg frng cbpxrg, naq evtug yrt cbpxrg ba cnagf) I assume that's all of them?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman that's what I got. For these type of puzzles, if you cross your eyes so that the images line up in the center, there's a flicker for any discrepancy between the two images, so you can solve them in seconds.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A reverse image search identified this game as ["Amazing Alex"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazing_Alex) by Rovio Entertainment. I’ve found similar screenshots of this game so I think it’s correct.

[image: Similar screenshot]

[Source](https://www.imore.com/amazing-alex-iphone-and-ipad-review)

Comment: I'm aware of Google's reverse image search and Tineye.  Are there other searches you used?

Comment: Google's reverse image search (and Google Lens??) gave me `Amazing Alex` results as well.